# ffmpeg 64bit Xcode

Tags: objective-c, macos, compilation, ffmpeg, 64-bit

I'm trying to use the ffmpeg libraries in Xcode on Mac. I want to address to 64bit-systems like Lion and Mountain Lion. I tried to compile with

```
./configure --enable-static --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-gpl --disable-doc --disable-programs --arch=x86_64 --cc=cc --disable-yasm --host-cflags="-arch x86_64" --host-ldflags="-arch x86_64" --prefix=ffmpeg
```

Then I copied the ffmpeg-directory (with lib and include folders) into my project folder. I added the .a-files to my project and added the .a files to "Link binaries with Libraries"). Also I adjusted the header and library folder in the project settings. So far so good.

I'm a beginner with those libraries, so I started with opening a video. Works fine.

Now I'm trying to decode a given input file. Therefore I looked at this example file: http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/1.0/decoding__encoding_8c-source.html

I copied the video_decode_example function. But at compiling I'm getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_decode_write_frame", referenced from:
    _video_decode_example in cutClass.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

What did I wrong at compiling ffmpeg?

Comment: What version of ffmpeg are you using?

Answer (score 2):

`decode_write_frame()` is not part of ffmpeg — it's part of the sample code you were referring to. Read the sample code more closely and implement your own equivalent. (The implementation in the `decoding_encoding.c` sample is almost certainly **not** something you'd want in production code -- it just writes every frame to disk as a [PGM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) image file.)

Comment: Oh yes, that's true. I forgot to copy those method. And thanks for your hint... but I couldn't find an example how to transcode a video :(

But now I have some more linker errors like this:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_BZ2_bzDecompress", referenced from:
      _matroska_decode_buffer in libavformat.a(matroskadec.o)
... and so on

Comment: Full answer will depend on what options you compiled ffmpeg with. The one error you mentioned, though, indicates that you need to link `libbz2` (from `/usr/lib`).